# How to compile Kotlin unit test code that uses hamcrest 'is'

Tags: unit-testing, junit, kotlin, hamcrest

I want to write a unit test for my Kotlin code and use junit/hamcrest matchers, I want to use the `is` method, but it is a reserved word in Kotlin.

How can I get the following to compile?

```
class testExample{
  @Test fun example(){
    assertThat(1, is(equalTo(1))
  }
}
```

Currently my IDE, InteliJ is highlighting that as a compilation error, saying it is expecting a `)` after `is`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In Kotlin, `is` is a reserved word . To get around this you need to escape the code using backticks, so the following will allow you to compile the code:

```
class testExample{
  @Test fun example(){
    assertThat(1, `is`(equalTo(1))
  }
}
```

Comment: You might be able to make use of infix operator maybe to allow `assertThat(1 is equalTo(1))`... but you would have to wrap a good bit I think. Maybe with the combination of some DSL style work you get to the point one can write `assertThat{ N isEqualTo 1}` but I'm not inclined to put that effort in... yet

Answer (score 46):

You can alias `is` to `Is` (for example) in the `import` statement using the `as` keyword.

For example:

```
 import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.`is` as Is
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/packages.html#imports

Comment: You would still need to reference the `is` function when you import it, so you would still need to escape it. But this is a nice trick that would help save you from escaping it all over the place.

Comment: That is true, just once, something like:
 
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.`is` as Is

Comment: At which point it's just a style thing. Personally, I'd rather escape the function name personally.

Comment: Up to you. With 'aliasing' you need to this only once

Answer (score 16):

As others pointed out, in Kotlin, `is` is a reserved word (see [Type Checks](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html)). But it's not a big problem with Hamcrest since [`is`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/Is.html) function is just a decorator. It's used for better code readability, but it's not required for proper functioning.

You are free to use a shorter Kotlin-friendly expression.

1. equality:

   ```
   assertThat(cheese, equalTo(smelly))
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   assertThat(cheese, `is`(equalTo(smelly)))
   ```
2. matcher decorator:

   ```
   assertThat(cheeseBasket, empty())
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   assertThat(cheeseBasket, `is`(empty()))
   ```

Another frequently used Hamcrest matcher is a type-check like

```
assertThat(cheese, `is`(Cheddar.class))
```

It's deprecated and it's not Kotlin-friendly. Instead, you're advised to use one of the following:

```
assertThat(cheese, isA(Cheddar.class))
assertThat(cheese, instanceOf(Cheddar.class))
```

Comment: Oh, this is actually quite nice to know. Never knew it was basically a redundant extra call.