# Why does it have to be the`is` in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, matcher

When trying to convert code from Java to Kotlin for an Espresso test,

Java code:

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is("Americano")))
  .perform(click());
```

Kotlin code:

```
onData(allOf(`is`(instanceOf(String::class.java)),
    `is`("Americano"))).perform(click())
```

The `'is'` is actually:

```
public static <T> Matcher<T> is(T value) {
    return Is.is(value);
}
```

Why does the syntax for it become `'is'` in Kotlin?

Comment: Because `is` is a reserved keyword in Kotlin.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025927/how-to-compile-kotlin-unit-test-code-that-uses-hamcrest-is, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is` is a reserved keyword in Kotlin. For interoperability with **Java** and other programming languages that can name fields or method like reserve words in Kotlin we use **backticks** to escape names. For example in your case method `is` from Java is escaped with backticks:

```
onData(allOf(`is`(instanceOf(String::class.java)),
`is`("Americano"))).perform(click())
```

Another example of escaping using `when` method of **Mockito** library:

```
Mockito.`when`(/*some method is called*/).thenReturn(/*return some result*/)
```

Documentation regarding [Calling Java code from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin):

> Some of the Kotlin keywords are valid identifiers in Java: **in**, **object**, **is**, etc. If a Java library uses a Kotlin keyword for a method, you can still call the method escaping it with the **backtick (`)** character:

```
foo.`is`(bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, identifiers that are also [hard keywords](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#hard-keywords) (but not soft ones) [have to be backticked](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin).

If you want to avoid backticks, you can make an utility extension function for that with a different name:

```
fun <T> Matcher<T>.isA(value: T) = `is`(value)`
```